# How can I prove $||A||_1=$ max$_{1\le j \le n}$ $\sum_{i=1} ^n$ $|A_{ij}|$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, summation, normed-spaces

How can I prove $||A||_1=$ max$_{1\le j \le n}$ $\sum_{i=1} ^n$ $|A_{ij}|$ ??

$A  \in R^{n\times n}$ , $x\in R^n$

The definition of 1 - norm of matrix is:

$||A||_1$ = max$_{x\ne 0}$ $\frac{||Ax||_1}{||x||_1}$

The I proceed to max$_{||x||=1}$ $||Ax||_1$ =max$_{||x||=1}$ $\sum_{i=1} ^n |A_{ij}x_i|$ ...

Now I cannot go on.... what should I do? Did I do wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging in $e_j$ (the $j^{\text{th}}$ standard basis vector) which has norm 1, we get $$\| A \|_1 = \max_{\|x \|_1 =1} \|Ax\|_1 \ge \| A e_j \|_1 = \sum^n_{i=1} \lvert A_{ij} \rvert.$$ Since this holds for all $j$, we have $$\|A\|_1 \ge \max_{1\le j \le n} \sum^n_{i=1} \lvert A_{ij} \rvert.$$ Conversely, for any $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|x\|_1 = 1$, we see $$Ax = \sum^n_{j=1} x_j \vec A_j$$ where $\vec A_j$ is the $j^{\text{th}}$ column of $A$. Then the triangle inequality gives $$\|Ax\|_1 \le \sum^n_{j=1} \lvert x_j \rvert \|\vec A_j \|_1 \le \left(\max_{1 \le j \le n} \| \vec A_j\|_1 \right) \sum^n_{j=1} \lvert x_j \rvert = \left(\max_{1 \le j \le n} \| \vec A_j\|_1 \right) \| x\|_1 = \max_{1 \le j \le n} \| \vec A_j\|_1.$$ But now just writing out what $\| \vec A_j\|_1$ is, we we have $$\| Ax \|_1 \le \max_{1\le j \le n} \sum^n_{i=1} \lvert A_{ij}\rvert.$$ Since this holds for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with $\| x\|_1 = 1$, it sill hold for the particular $x^* \in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|x^* \|_1=1$ which achieves the maximum. Thus $$\|A\|_1 = \|Ax^*\|_1 \le \max_{1\le j \le n} \sum^n_{i=1} \lvert A_{ij}\rvert.$$ Hence $$\|A\|_1 = \max_{1\le j \le n} \sum^n_{i=1} \lvert A_{ij}\rvert.$$

Comment: I think that $x$ should be =[1 0 0 ..0] something like that, is it right? I mean one of elements are 1 and all the othere are zero

Comment: That is what $e_j$ is in the first line (the $j^{\text{th}}$ element is 1 and the others are zero). Other than that, no; I just mean some $x \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $$\| x\|_1 := \sum_{j=1}^n \lvert x_j \rvert = 1.$$

Comment: After I asked this question, I got an idea for the problem: That is, in A, there is an maximum, call it T and then T multiply by 1 must be the maximum of the problem, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in $A$, there is a maximum." A maximum what?

Comment: I mean that an element of matrix must be a maximum.... Like A=[1 2 3] then 3 must be maximum... I mean something like that

Comment: This problem shows us the the maximum will be achieved by one of the vectors $e_j$. But at the start, we can't know that so looking at  $Ae_j$ only gives $$\| A \|_1 \ge \|Ae_j\|_1 = \sum^n_{i=1} \lvert A_{ij} \rvert, \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{ for all } j = 1,\ldots, n.$$ These vectors tell us nothing about the reverse inequality. For the reverse inequality, you need to look at arbitrary $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|x \|_1 = 1$ (or you can just look at the one which achieves the maximum but you don't know that it is $e_j$ for some $j$) and try to get an upper bound for $\|A x\|_1.$

Comment: That $A$ isn't a square matrix. Sure a square matrix must have at least one maximal element, but that doesn't really help you. You need to look at sums along the columns of $A$, not just single elements.